# Can demultiplexers be synthesized?

Tags: hdl

In my digital design module involving HDL (Verilog) and a ton of RTL diagrams, our lecturer always said never to use demultiplexers because they do not exist.

Why is that?

Comment: Please provide some context for this statement, such as a citation for an article. It would also be helpful if you could show the specific HDL code that you were told not to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demultiplexers/decoders are commonly used in SSI/MSI logic because it's a convenient way to get an array of AND gates with various combinations of true and inverted inputs in a single package. ([Example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/399543/11683))

But that's really all they are. In FPGA design, each AND gate gets synthesized directly, sometimes combined with other functions into a single LUT. There's no particular reason to use a "demultiplexer" in the source code — it's more likely to obfuscate the design rather than making it clearer.

Comment: Fantastic! I'm sorry I don't have more info on this. I just was revising HDL and I remembered this from a previous module.